# Number of ways to select notes for a melody (with repetition)

Tags: combinatorics

The question I have is:

> Find the number of melodies that consist of 4 white notes and 2 black
>   notes from a set of 7 white notes and 5 black notes. Notes are allowed
>   to be repeated.

This is pretty tricky for me, since most of the permutations I did don't involve repetition.

Assuming the first 4 notes are white, then I have $7^4$ ways ways to select the white notes. Then I have $5^2$ ways to select the black notes. So there are $7^4 * 5^2$ ways to find unique sets of notes.

What I'm struggling with is how to find the number of ways to permute the positions of the notes within a set. Because notes are allowed to be repeated, there will be different cases to take into account. Any help will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a total of $4 + 2 = 6$ notes in the melody.  Choose two positions for the black notes.  Doing so also determines the positions of the four white notes since the remaining four positions in the melody must be filled with white notes.  Since notes may be repeated, each position for a black note can be filled in $5$ ways and each position for a white note can be filled in $7$ ways.  Hence, the number of melodies consisting of two black and four white notes is
$$\binom{6}{2}7^45^2$$

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot